# Nested <apex:repeat> in an <apex:map>

Tags: visualforce, google-map

I'm running into some odd errors with a nested `apex:repeat` inside of an `apex:map` (on API 34.0). My code looks like this:

```
    <apex:map width="500px" height="500px" center="53704">
        <apex:repeat value="{!matches}" var="match">
            <apex:mapMarker title="{!match.Provider__r.Name}"
             position="{latitude:{!match.Provider__r.Latitude_Display__c},longitude:{!match.Provider__r.Longitude_Display__c}}">
                <apex:mapInfoWindow>
                    <apex:repeat value="{!$ObjectType.Account.FieldSets.Provider_Detail_Pin}" var="f">
                        <apex:outputPanel layout="block" style="font-weight: bold;">
                            <apex:outputField value="{! match.Provider__r[f] }"/>
                        </apex:outputPanel>
                    </apex:repeat>
                </apex:mapInfoWindow>
             </apex:mapMarker>
        </apex:repeat>
    </apex:map>
```

This results in an odd error:

```
Result: [COMPILE FAILED]: (ReferralMap) <apex:outputPanel> cannot be used inside <apex:map> in the markup  (Line: 1, Column: -1)
```

If I remove the `outputPanel` I get a message saying that `outputField` is not acceptable. If I remove that and just use an expression, that also fails.

As soon as I remove the second `apex:repeat` and hard code fields instead of a FieldSet, the errors go away and I can have an `outputPanel` in the map. That said, I'd much rather have a FieldSet!

Any ideas?

Later on in the page, I use this pattern very successfully, it only fails inside the `<apex:map>`:

```
    <apex:repeat value="{!providersMatchingSome}" var="match"> 
        <apex:pageBlockSection title="{!match.Provider__r.Name}">
            <apex:repeat value="{!$ObjectType.Account.FieldSets.Provider_Detail_Block}" var="f">
                <apex:outputField value="{!match.Provider__r[f]}" /><br/>
        </apex:repeat>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:repeat>
```

Comment: Related SFDC document, showing an example without the 2nd nested repeat tag: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_maps_info_windows.htm

Comment: Hi @MarkPond, that's what I'm trying to do, but I'm trying to use a FieldSet to determine what shows in the MapInfoWindow. Hardcoding the fields works, but we want the flexibility of letting the admin adjust what fields display.

Comment: Yes, I see that. I just wanted to include a link to an SFDC document that demonstrated your working solution from an official perspective. I agree that the second repeat tag breaks the implementation.

Comment: Ah good point, thanks! The error message is very confusing...

Answer (score -1):

What you describe makes perfect sense to me. Assuming you're using either a wrapper class or a list controller, when you nest the 2nd `<apex:repeat>` inside the first one, the compiler is expecting the contents of that repeat to be appended to the outer repeat.

```
match.$ObjectType.Account.FieldSets.Provider_Detail_Pi
```

Most likely isn't going to be contained inside your wrapper class or list controller var is it? If it were, then you could iterate on it. If not, you can't. Thus, the reason for the error.

The reality is, a wrapper can only iterate on one field at a time in the sequence that it's stored in the class. The nested repeat is intended for use to pull additional records out where you have related objects that are nested within other objects which have fields within them that also repeat.

Comment: Hey @crmprogdev, I just edited the question to show that I use this pattern just fine elsewhere in the code. I'm iterating through a list of objects, and then iterating through the fieldset to decide what fields to display. This is pretty bog standard dynamic visualforce, it's only erroring when inside the new google map component.

Comment: Do you use it with a list controller to do that?

Comment: Nope, standard controller (though I do have a extension to select a specific subset of the related objects, but that's all it is doing). There are no wrapper classes either. This is just how you do related lists with fieldsets. I've never had it fail, just within the new map component.